# Make elements go to the next column in absolute positioned parent

Tags: css

There are many elements in my code.

**#relative_float**

The blue element which contains everything **has to be floated** (because of reasons) and **its position is relative** (just to help wrapping absolute positioned element).

**#absolute**
The gray element which is in #relative_float and contains links. Its **width** property is **auto** and it has a **min-width**.

Here's the CSS for my code:

```css
#relative_float {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: #99C;
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  right: 200px;
}

#relative_float #absolute {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /*position*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

#absolute a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="relative_float">
  <div id="absolute">
    <a>link1</a>
    <a>link2</a>
    <a>link3</a>
    <a>link4</a>
    <a>link5</a>
    <a>link6</a>
    <a>link7</a>
    <a>link8</a>
    <a>link9</a>
    <a>link10</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you see in the fiddle, the sixth link and others after it place out of their parent. I need to make them to go to the next column after the end.

I tried CSS 3 columns, but it didn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you... For every link, open a a different URL. Just use `-moz-column-count: 2;` by using its divide-by-two column. You set the number of columns you want. Like for example: `-moz-column-count: 4;`

#### CSS code

```
#relative_float {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #99C;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 200px;
}

#relative_float #absolute {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    /*position*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

#absolute a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

#### HTML code

```
 <section id="relative_float">
      <div id="absolute">
        <a href="#">link1</a>
        <a href="#">link2</a>
        <a href="#">link3</a>
        <a href="#">link4</a>
        <a href="#">link5</a>
        <a href="#">link6</a>
        <a href="#">link7</a>
        <a href="#">link8</a>
        <a href="#">link9</a>
        <a href="#">link10</a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

You use the other elements to clearly differentiate the column, like:

```
-moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
-moz-column-gap: 40px;
-moz-column-rule-style: solid;
-moz-column-rule-color: lightblue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gray element has a fixed height :)

```
#relative_float #absolute {
  min-width: 100px;
  /* height: 150px; */
  line-height:0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /*position*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i read it wrong, you want your element side by side? :) or what?

Comment: I just want what I said :) and I did give the code in my question

Comment: If you remove your display:inline-block, you get the effect you want

Comment: relax @john im trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

It works here...

```css
#relative_float {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: #99C;
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  right: 200px;
}
#relative_float #absolute {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  /*position*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

#absolute a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="relative_float">
  <div id="absolute">
    <a>link1</a>
    <a>link2</a>
    <a>link3</a>
    <a>link4</a>
    <a>link5</a>
    <a>link6</a>
    <a>link7</a>
    <a>link8</a>
    <a>link9</a>
    <a>link10</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the links should have width and height , and it's not working, just not showing, what would happen if you double the links?